# Convergent series in the real world with equal time for each term

Tags: spacetime, discrete

A few months ago someone was explaining a philosophical principle in Aikido (a martial art) which involved a convergent series. The analogy he used was that, say you have a pool, and each day the pool half fills with leaves, so on day one, it would be empty then day two it would be half full and then on the third day it would be three quarters full and so on.   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$
I tried to explain that this series would eventually converge to to length of the pool. but on further consideration it seems obvious that the time to fill the pool would be infinite or at least undefined because each term in the infinite series takes one day. but then again the physical world is limited to various constants such as the Planck length etc. making the series more like $\sum_{n=1}^{l_p}(1/n)^2$

So my question is, can convergent series have any 'significance' in the real world and do infinite series actual 'exist'.

Comment: Given you mention that on the third day it would be three quarters full, are you asking about the summation of 1/(2^n) instead of 1/(n^2)?

Comment: Yes thankyou @BowlOfRed, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if one talks about the mathematical problem, it is a mathematical problem and there is nothing such as "atoms" or "Planck length" or "Planck's constant" in mathematics. The sum is convergent and may be evaluated e.g. using Fourier series and the result is
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \approx 1.645 $$
The Greek letter represents the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). Yes, this sum and many similar sums frequency appear in physics. They are almost everywhere in loop calculations in quantum field theory. But for a simpler example, consider the energy carried by thermal radiation confined to a wire.

More famously, the related sum
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} = \zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90} \approx 1.082 $$
where the integral has the fourth power and not the second power appears in the calculation of the total energy carried by the black-body radiation – that's the radiation emitted by the black body. The total energy ends up being proportional to the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) and this constant, $\sigma$, is proportional to $\zeta(4)$ which is the sum above.

Note that the argument in $\zeta(4)$ is the same number that appears as the exponent in the sum. The $\zeta$ (zeta) function may be defined by this sum. $\zeta(x)$ diverges for $x\to 1$ but it is a rational multiple of $\pi^{2k}$ for $x=2k$ where $k$ is an integer. See e.g. [this recipe how to evaluate](http://motls.blogspot.com/2014/01/a-recursive-evaluation-of-zeta-of.html?m=1) the function without a calculator up to $\zeta(14)$ or what your patience allows. The values of $\zeta(x)$ for $x=3,5,7,\dots $ and other odd numbers are irrational and (almost certainly) transcendental, not even rational multiples of any powers of $\pi$ or something like that.

The sum seemingly diverges for $x\lt 1$ but the values of $\zeta(x)$ may actually be evaluated for all complex values of $x$ using the "analytical continuation". That gives us $\zeta(0)=1+1+1+\dots = -1/2$ and $\zeta(-1)=1+2+3+4+5+\dots = -1/12$. The values of $\zeta(x)$ for even negative integers is zero while $\zeta(x)$ for odd negative $x$ are rational numbers, with alternating signs.

Both in the black body case and in quantum field theories, the sums appear in their "almost exact forms". The number $n$ is ultimately proportional to some frequencies but the electromagnetic field exists for all frequencies and by the Lorentz symmetry, it behaves in the idealized way for all values of $n$so no "atoms" really spoil the result. In some other medium, atoms may modify the sum substantially for large enough $n$.